# Style a WPF's ListView Header's hover color

Tags: wpf

Anyone know how to style the header hover color of a WPF ListView?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to create a style for the `GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle` property. Add the hover effect by setting some trigger to the Style.

For example:

```
 <ListView VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="63" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyle1}" >
                <GridViewColumn/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

and the Style can be created like so:

```
  <Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I was looking for a way do disable the row hover, and found this question to help me find a solution. Maybe this can help others                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">               <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>