# bind a collection without using list view wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I want to bind a list without listview because I'm tired of the default styles of the listview and that blue selection. The list I'm trying to bind is not a table. It's a question app (s.th like google form). I want to load the questions witch needs binding  I don't have enough flexibility. Is there any other way to bind list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **DataGrid** : https://wpf-tutorial.com/en/90/the-datagrid-control/datagrid-with-row-details/

This control allow total flexibility.

[image]

Comment: Does datagrid have blue selection like listview?

Comment: Blue selection ?

Comment: Wow! I see. I thinks that's way better than listview for my app. thankyou!

Comment: yes. list view gets blue when hover on it witch is suck.

Comment: A datagrid allow you to display data as you want. You are free to modify this as well.

Comment: "The app I'm making is not a table"!!

Comment: I shouldn't have write that but I will edit it

Answer (score 1):

**Option1.** Apply a custom tyle over your `ListView` (change the hover like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338763/style-a-wpfs-listview-headers-hover-color)).

```
<Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and

```
<ListView VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="63" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyle1}" >
            <GridViewColumn/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**Option2.** use `<ListBox/>` or `<ItemsControl/>`, they are Base classes that `ListView` is derived from them and their styles differ from `ListView`'s style so they might be useful for your usecase.